# Karate !contains is not working while matching sub-sets of JSON keys and arrays

Tags: rest, automation, karate

I have these scenario steps:

```
@SomeDataType
 Scenario: Find records 
   Given url 'http://xxxx.Staging.xxxx.com:port/xxxx/data?dataType=patient'
   And method get
   And print 'LoggedData: ' + response
   Then match response[*].data._type contains 'patient'
   And match response[*].data._type !contains 'exams'
```

The last "And" step didn't pass and it looks like the step skipped in the report (marked in Yellow).

I want to check if _type in the JSON array contains 'exams' value, why "!contains" isn't working?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Without your complete example and data it is impossible to tell. I tried to guess below, hopefully you can figure out what to fix. You can paste the below into a fresh `Scenario:` and see it working for yourself:

```
* def response = [{ data: { _type: 'foo' }}, { data: { _type: 'patient' }}]
* match response[*].data._type contains 'patient'
* match response[*].data._type !contains 'exams'
```

Comment: It's not working and tried the examples in the documentation.

Comment: @NaelAbdeljawad the time has come to point you to this page, all the best ! https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue